# image classification, what java library or gui interface

Tags: java, user-interface, neural-network, image-recognition

I want to compare 1 image to 2 different image sets to see which set it belongs to.

The 2 image sets will be spectrometer images generated from different substances. A spectrometer will then generate a image from an unknown substance. This image will then be classified into 1 of the 2 sets to determine what the unknown substance is.

I tried using the Java ANN library Encog. The example code they gave worked fine but then stopped working.
I know matlab has some good software but I would prefer free software.

It would be perfect if there were some sample code to just copy paste as a first test to classify easily distinguishable images. Then build up from there.

I have given two different spectrometer images below just to give an idea of what I am talking about

two sample spectrometer images are:
[image]
[image]

If anyone has any ideas I would be grateful.

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code for what you've tried so far?

Comment: I practically copy pasted the code from  https://github.com/encog/encog-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/encog/examples/neural/image/ImageNeuralNetwork.java  but it doesn't clasiffy images properly, here's the output  Training Stopped...
What is: C:\Users\Mikhail Janowski\Desktop\fmd\imgs\incandescent.png, it seems to be: energysaving.png
What is: C:\Users\Mikhail Janowski\Desktop\fmd\imgs\energysaving.png, it seems to be: energysaving.png  as you can see it classifies all images the same

Comment: I downloaded the encog library from  https://github.com/downloads/encog/encog-java-core/encog-core-3.1.0-release.zip